# How to modify code to keep destination cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I recently came into usage of the code below:

```
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Table")

sht1.Range("K10").Copy sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
sht1.Range("G15").Copy sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

I was hoping if the community could advise how to modify it to allow the destination cell to keep its formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a value transfer, no need for `Copy`.

Note that `sht1` is actually a `Variant` if you do not specifically declare it `As Worksheet`.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Table")

With sh2
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sh1.Range("K10").Value
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sh1.Range("G15").Value
End With
```

Comment: hi, i tried using your suggested code but I'm getting an error that an object is needed....I'm not sure what to do.